# $K_0$ an $KH_0$ of a normal crossing variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

Let $k$ be a field (say, algebraically closed to fix the ideas) and let $X$ be a strict (aka simple) normal crossing variety over $k$, so that $X$ is union of regular varieties with intersection that is also regular.

Then the question is the following. Is it true that $X$ is $K_p$ regular for all $p\leq 0$? Recall that a scheme $X$ is called $K_p$ regular if all the groups $N^qK_p(X)$ are trivial for each $q>0$, where $N^qK_p(X) = K_p(X)$ for $q=0$ and $N^qK_p(X) = \ker[i_0^*:N^{q-1}K_p(X\times \mathbb{A}^1)\to N^{q-1}K_p(X)]$ for $q>0$.

Some words of context: the groups $N^q$ are a measure for the failure of homotopy invariance for the group $K_p$. It is also not hard to show that if $X$ is $K_p$-regular, then it is $K_{p-1}$-regular, so that the question can be reformulated just in terms of $K_0$ groups (and this justifies the title of the question).

P.S. I'm aware that this is not a globally accepted definition of normal crossing variety (it's kind of sloppy, indeed). I'm willing to change it if this is helping in constructing examples/counterexamples.

P.P.S. There are results in the literature that should fix the affine case. Can one say anything if $X$ is, say, projective?